# how do I work around this error while copying SVN repository by svnsync?

Tags: svn, svnsync

I am copying a repository by using svnsync and am receiving this error on the same revision every time.

> Transmitting file data ...svnsync: REPORT of 'https://svn1.avlux.net/xxxxxx.net': Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated https://svn1.avlux.net)

It is a large revision and I don't have admin access to the server.  Is there a way around this, even if it involves checking out and copying the revision manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to copy the repo once or are you trying to setup an ongoing mirroring scheme?

If it's the former you could let sync go until it fails, then do a diff between the revision it failed on and the previous revision and output that to a file.  So if the rev that failed was 135 it would be something like this:

```
svn diff -r134:135 http://your/repo/url > patch.diff
```

Then you can apply this patch file to a working copy of the new repo.

```
patch -p0 -i patch.diff
```

Then just commit the changes to that working copy and kick off svnsync again.

This is pretty hackish, but it might work.

NOTE: I didn't test any of the commands, there might be some syntax errors, but the general approach should work in theory.

Comment: I am trying to copy the repo once.  The diff didn't quite work, as it leaves out binary files, instead I am trying to checkout the troublesome revision, use winmerge to merge the changes to the new repo and syncing from there.

Comment: did it work? How did you solve this issue in the end? I am all the more interested that I started getting the same error in my svnsyncs tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolved the issue by:
-   Update (Apache and svn to latest)
-   Turn on svn V2 protocol (apache config under the location)
            SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol On