# SVN Sync blocks: Could not read response body

Tags: svn, svnsync

this may be a duplicate of [how do I work around this error while copying SVN repository by svnsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227634/how-do-i-work-around-this-error-while-copying-svn-repository-by-svnsync)

I'm setting up a repository sync.
everthing works fine until revision 3213 (let call this as **R**).
After that the *svnsync sync* command gives me this error:

```
svnsync: REPORT of 'MY_REPO_URL': Could not read response body: connection was closed by server
```

I think it depends on revison **R + 1** being quite big.
The svn-book suggest to not allow anyone except svnsync to write on the mirror repository.

How do i solve it?

```
svnsync, version 1.6.9 (r901367)
   compiled Feb 12 2010, 16:03:09
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem, and the specifics of the solution depends on server you are synchronizing to, but seems to revolve around the destination server rejecting connections, and of two examples found on the web, the rejection is due to the destination server "timing out" the synchronization process.

- [VisualSVN http-timeout](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/38944-svnsync-Could-not-read-response-body)
- [Apache TimeOut](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#timeout) (and SO's own) [TimeOut Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614598/apache-timeout-configuration)

I've got an Apache destination server, and the solution was to change the default TimeOut from 60s to something higher (I'm using 1 hr to clear the backlog of commits) The amount of time you set will obviously depend on your experience.

Sam T.