# Apache Timeout Configuration

Tags: apache, timeout

We are using apache 2.2 version and we have three servers configured for load balancing purpose (like as below)

```
BalancerMember http://node1:port/ route=node1
BalancerMember xxxx://node2:xxxx/ route=node2
BalancerMember xxxx://node3:xxxx/ route=node3
```

However the backend application nodes configured in balancer member requires lot of processing time and hence we were facing issues related to timeout like as below

> “The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line
>   from remote server ”

As I had a customised .conf file ,I had to add the below lines explicitly to avoid picking default timeout value from default http-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost server:port>
Timeout 500
<Proxy  balancer://xxxxx>
BalancerMember http://node1:port/ route=node1 timeout=500
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

So now my questions are:

1. Do I need to explicitly configure timeout value at both the levels as shown above,
   a) Timeout 500 outside Proxy.

   b) timeout=500 at BalancerMember level.

   I read in internet that if the timeout of the Apache BalancerMember is
   not configured the global Apache timout is inherited there. Please suggest..
2. Also please suggest the exact parameters needs to be tuned when huge
   concurrent requests are anticipated ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,any pointers on this please?